# Rectangular bins on leaflet map

Tags: d3.js, svg, leaflet

I came across Peter Beshai example of https://peterbeshai.com/geo-explore/rectbin-svg/ and I want to know is it possible to make rectangular bins on the leaflet.js map or is it has to be a layer like for hexagons there is L.hexbin layer??

Answer (score 0):

**[Update]** Having re-read your question I don't think you're asking if you can make rectangles with rectbin or not!

The example uses [d3-rectbin](https://github.com/fabid/d3-rectbin) and you can set both .dx and .dy to the value you want - set them the same for a square, different for a rectangle.

You can try it out here:

http://blockbuilder.org/fabid/a1a7d04bdd34c2096eaf

In that example you will see the following lines of code. Change .dx and .dy to be different values.

```
var size = 20;
var rectbin = d3.rectbin()
  .dx(size)
  .dy(size);
```